# What is the Best Second Hash function when using Double Hashing?

Tags: hashtable, collision

I saw in some of the forums that people used:

```
7-(key mod 7)  or 6-(key mod 6)
```

This is used for computing the second hash function of Double Hashing for any large values of the key.
Is there any importance to the usage of that 6(not even a prime no.) or 7?

Or is it just to randomly generate some value unlike linear probing and quadratic probing?

References:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Hashtablewithdoublehashing.htm
http://www.cse.unt.edu/~donr/courses/2050/HashTables.php

Comment: "many forums" - but no linked references....

Comment: With regards to the question title - there is *no* "the best" hash function. It depends on the data you are hashing and how it's being used. The best recommendation for the suitability of a second hash function is probably "different from the first hash function"...

Comment: Yes.. you are right. But i just want to make sure that, for hash function we generally use key % tablesize, similarly is there any such hash function for second hash function. Any way i understood the logic behind it.Thanks for your comments.