# What if a collision still exists after applying the double hashing algorithm?

Tags: hash, hashtable, double-hashing

I have a hash table of size 8 where I want to insert the values (0, 1, 8, 9, 5, 33).
I tried it with hashing which has collision then I tried the double hashing algorithm but the collision still  occurs as follows:

> Hashing = H1(k) = k % 8
>   Double Hashing = H2(k) = M - (k % M)

```
H1(0) = 0 % 8 = 0   
H1(1) = 1 % 8 = 1  
H1(8) = 8 % 8 = 0 -----> Needs double hashing ----> 7-(8 % 7)=7-1=6 (we forward 6 steps from the current position which is 0 and it will become 6).  
H1(9) = 9 % 8 = 1----> Needs double hashing ---> 7 - (9%7)=7-2=5(we forward 5 steps from the current position which is 1 and it will become 6 again).
```

Now I am stuck here and I dont know what to do. 
Note: I do not want to use any other method, I want to use only double hashing.
Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify - are you forced to use H2(k)? or can you use a different hashing function for the secondary hash?

Comment: @RannLifshitz
What if I know both methods.

Comment: Then you are good to go. See my detailed answer below. Just an issue of properly using the double hashing algorithm buddy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use the double hashing algorithm as intended.

As mentioned in this very nice [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/double-hashing/):

> Double hashing can be done using :

```
(hash1(key) + i * hash2(key)) % TABLE_SIZE
```

> Here hash1() and hash2() are hash functions and TABLE_SIZE
>   is the size of hash table. (We repeat by increasing `i` when a collision
>   occurs)

And the given example is (in your case):

```
H1(0) = 0 % 8 = 0   
H1(1) = 1 % 8 = 1  
H1(8) = 8 % 8 = 0
   H2(8) = 7 - (8 % 7)= 7-1 = 6
   // double hashing algorithm start : i == 1
   (H1(8) + i*H2(8)) % TABLE_SIZE = (0 + 1*6) % 8 = 6       

H1(9) = 9 % 8 = 1
   H2(9) = 7 - (9 % 7)= 7-2 = 5
   // double hashing algorithm start : i == 1
   (H1(9) + i*H2(9)) % TABLE_SIZE = (1 + 1*5) % 8 = 6 --> collision (increment i to 2)
   (H1(9) + i*H2(9)) % TABLE_SIZE = (1 + 2*5) % 8 = 3 --> no collision
```

Additional References:

- [Double Hashing in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing)
- [Double Hashing Example](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse326/00wi/handouts/lecture16/sld025.htm)
- [Hashing - Double Hashing Collision Resolution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDMc4hg1lUk)

Bonus:

- [What is the Best Second Hash function when using Double Hashing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225663/what-is-the-best-second-hash-function-when-using-double-hashing)

Answer (score 1):

In double hashing, you repeat the 2nd hash step until a free spot is found.
The process is to keep adding *H2(k)* to the last index (modulo size) to generate the next index.

In your example, this translates to:

> H1(9) = 9 % 8 = 1
>     H2(9) = 7 - (9 % 7) = 5
>
> Attempted spots: 1, 6, 3, 0, 5, 2, 7, 4

So the 9 value would be stored at index 3.

Comment: @Amit, I did not understand your answer, please help me in the "Attempted spots", I mean I want to know how I can dig into next step. How will 9 go to 3?